gnome-network-displays
I installed 24.04 using an Acer laptop with 8 GB RAM and 256GB disk. I tried to use gnome-network-displays to connect to a Samsung TV. I am getting the following errors:
gnome-network-displays:6211): Gnd-WARNING **: 21:50:04.862: NdCCProvider: Failed to resolve Avahi service: Resolving failed: Timeout reached

(gnome-network-displays:6211): Gnd-WARNING **: 21:50:04.863: NdCCProvider: Failed to resolve Avahi service: Resolving failed: Timeout reached

(gnome-network-displays:6211): Gnd-WARNING **: 21:50:23.818: CcHttpServer: Pipeline fault: Internal data stream error.


got the same problem and my device has P2P capability and opted for the Xorg server from the login menu.
$ flatpak run org.gnome.NetworkDisplays

(gnome-network-displays:2): Gnd-WARNING **: 08:13:49.476: CcMediaFactory: Selected audio-only media profile PROFILE_AUDIO_VORBIS. Setting factory profile to 10
(gnome-network-displays:2): Gnd-WARNING **: 08:13:51.617: NdCCProvider: Failed to resolve Avahi service: Resolving failed: Timeout reached
(gnome-network-displays:2): Gnd-WARNING **: 08:14:41.683: NdCCProvider: Failed to resolve Avahi service: Resolving failed: Timeout reached
(gnome-network-displays:2): Gnd-WARNING **: 08:14:52.678: CcMediaFactory: Selected audio-only media profile PROFILE_AUDIO_VORBIS. Setting factory profile to 10

What is this? There is no details as to what this info is or means. Please edit the question and add some details.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
